# PlotRange is redundant?

Tags: plotting

In trying to control the axis range when plotting a function, it seems that the PlotRange attribute is redundant. For example:

```
y := a Cosh[x/a]
a = 2;
Plot[y, {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 10}}]
```

[image]

So, I apparently need to write the x-range twice. Of course, this is reasonable if the plot range is different than the axis range, but in the example above, I only want to use a different axis range for the y-axis. I want the x-range to match the x-axis range.

Is there a way to express this without entering the range twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy, just specify one range only in `PlotRange`:

```
y := a Cosh[x/a]
a = 2;
Plot[y, {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {1, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: I see. I had this idea, but I thought that the PlotRange argument had to be a list of lists, and if it is entered only such, then it does not work. I did not realize that it can also accept a plain pair.

Comment: Longer, but equivalent: `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, 10}}`